# Errors in bash scripts

Tags: bash, unix

I have a couple of errors in my script which I built in CentOS then deployed to Unix. I have the shebang `#!/bin/bash` on top of my scripts and execute my script using `bash myscript.sh`

LINE in script:

```
 existing[0]=""
```

> ERROR: existing[0]=: not found

LINE in script: not sure if its this -

```
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
```

or this one -

```
if [[ $sftp_status != 0 ]]; then
```

> ERROR: syntax error at line 118: `i=$' unexpected

LINE in script:

```
i=$((i + 1))
```

Comment: These individual lines don't help! Share the full code

Comment: try running script in debug mode. `bash -x myscript.sh`.

Comment: Apologies as I cannot extract the whole script here. It's currently in some server which I cannot pull out.

Answer (score 2):

if you have the shebang line on top, you can set the execute permission and run the script as `./<scriptname>`. You dont need the `bash <scriptname>`.

Those syntax seems to valid to me and i will doubt if this is bash. Try `/bin/bash  <scriptname>` and see if it helps.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think this is coming from bash either. In particular, I can't find "at line" in the bash executable (either bash v3 or v4), so I'm pretty sure those error messages are coming from something else.

Comment: I had to replace those sections with double brackets [[ ]]  with just single brackets []. Still suspicious though how come it fails on bash syntax